# How to get values from list view in an array

Tags: java, listview

First im getting array values from server and show in list view. After showing in list view , their are edit texts in the list from where i can change the text that i have shown in list view. No i want to again resend the updated list view values to the server that creating a problem for me .

```
public class AdapterLeaveDateCalenderItem extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<LeaveStaEndDTO> leaveStaEndDTOS33;

    public AdapterLeaveDateCalenderItem(Context context, List<LeaveStaEndDTO> leaveStaEndDTOS) {
        this.context = context;
        this.leaveStaEndDTOS33 = leaveStaEndDTOS;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return leaveStaEndDTOS33.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return leaveStaEndDTOS33.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return leaveStaEndDTOS33.get(position).getMonth();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view55= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.leave_fragment_calender_item,parent,false);
        LeaveStaEndDTO leaveStaEndDTO33=leaveStaEndDTOS33.get(position);
        ((TextView)view55.findViewById(R.id.dateGetLeave)).setText(String.valueOf(leaveStaEndDTO33.getDate()));
        ((EditText)view55.findViewById(R.id.morningGetLeave)).setText(String.valueOf(leaveStaEndDTO33.getMorningValue()));
        ((EditText)view55.findViewById(R.id.afternoonGetLeave)).setText(String.valueOf(leaveStaEndDTO33.getAfternoonValue()));
        return view55;
    }
}
```

This is model class

```
public class LeaveStaEndDTO {

    int id;
    int morningValue;
    int afternoonValue;
    Boolean weekend;
    int holyday;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    String dayCode;
    String date;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getMorningValue() {
        return morningValue;
    }

    public void setMorningValue(int morningValue) {
        this.morningValue = morningValue;
    }

    public int getAfternoonValue() {
        return afternoonValue;
    }

    public void setAfternoonValue(int afternoonValue) {
        this.afternoonValue = afternoonValue;
    }

    public Boolean getWeekend() {
        return weekend;
    }

    public void setWeekend(Boolean weekend) {
        this.weekend = weekend;
    }

    public int getHolyday() {
        return holyday;
    }

    public void setHolyday(int holyday) {
        this.holyday = holyday;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getDayCode() {
        return dayCode;
    }

    public void setDayCode(String dayCode) {
        this.dayCode = dayCode;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Now this is the main class

```
public class LeavesFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView l_startDate,l_endDate;
    ListView calenderLeavesTotal;
    EditText textArea_information;
    public static String encoded33="";
    public List<LeaveStaEndDTO> leaveStaEndDTOList;
    ImageView picLoaderLeave,submitLeaveNew;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View viewlv=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leaves, container, false);
        calenderLeavesTotal = (ListView)viewlv.findViewById(R.id.listViewLeavesCalender);
        leaveStaEndDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        submitLeaveNew = (ImageView)viewlv.findViewById(R.id.submitLeaveNew);
        textArea_information = (EditText)viewlv.findViewById(R.id.textArea_information);
        picLoaderLeave = (ImageView)viewlv.findViewById(R.id.img_leave_crea_upload);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)viewlv.findViewById(R.id.spinnerYear);
        final Spinner spinnerLeave = (Spinner)viewlv.findViewById(R.id.spinnerLeaveType);
        l_startDate=(TextView) viewlv.findViewById(R.id.leave_start);
        l_endDate=(TextView) viewlv.findViewById(R.id.leave_end);




        calenderLeavesTotal.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String clickableId=String.valueOf(leaveStaEndDTOList.get(position).getId());
                        String clickableDate=String.valueOf(leaveStaEndDTOList.get(position).getDate());
                        String clickableMorning=String.valueOf(leaveStaEndDTOList.get(position).getMorningValue());


                Toast.makeText(getContext(), clickableId+"\n"+clickableDate+"\n"+clickableMorning, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("2020");
        categories.add("2021");
        categories.add("2022");
        categories.add("2023");
        categories.add("2024");
        categories.add("2025");
        categories.add("2026");
        categories.add("2027");
        categories.add("2028");
        categories.add("2029");
        categories.add("2030");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String tu=  String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
                utils.creLeaveYear = tu;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<SelectDTO> leavesTypes = new ArrayAdapter<SelectDTO>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, utils.leavesTypeList);
        leavesTypes.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerLeave.setAdapter(leavesTypes);
        spinnerLeave.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                SelectDTO clickedDTo2 =(SelectDTO) parent.getSelectedItem();
                displayLeavesTypes(clickedDTo2);

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        l_startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                l_startDate.setText(year+"-"+(monthOfYear + 1)+ "-"+ dayOfMonth);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        l_endDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (l_startDate.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please select start date first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                    l_endDate.setText(year + "-"+(monthOfYear + 1) +"-"+ dayOfMonth);
                                    getStaEndDateResponse();

                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
                }

        });

        picLoaderLeave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_image_dialogue);
                TextView captureImage=dialog.findViewById(R.id.captureImage);
                TextView selectGallery=dialog.findViewById(R.id.selectGallery);
                TextView canDialog=dialog.findViewById(R.id.canBtn);

                captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                    }
                });
                selectGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 22);

                    }
                });

                canDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }
        });

        submitLeaveNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        return viewlv;

    }

    private void getStaEndDateResponse() {

        String endDate=l_endDate.getText().toString().trim();
        String staDate=l_startDate.getText().toString().trim();
        utils.creLeaveStartDate = staDate;
        utils.creLeaveEndDate = endDate;

        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progress.setTitle("Date Response");
        progress.setMessage("Loading...");
        progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
        progress.show();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSet=getContext().getSharedPreferences(utils.SHARED_PREF_SET,MODE_PRIVATE);
        user_token=sharedPreferencesSet.getString(utils.TEXT_SET,"");
        utils.bear="Bearer ";


        final RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i=0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            LeaveStaEndDTO leaveStaEndDTO=new LeaveStaEndDTO();
                            leaveStaEndDTO.setMorningValue(jsonObject.getInt("morningValue"));
                            leaveStaEndDTO.setAfternoonValue(jsonObject.getInt("afternoonValue"));
                            leaveStaEndDTO.setWeekend(jsonObject.getBoolean("weekend"));
                            leaveStaEndDTO.setYear(jsonObject.getInt("year"));
                            leaveStaEndDTO.setMonth(jsonObject.getInt("month"));
                            leaveStaEndDTO.setDay(jsonObject.getInt("day"));
                            leaveStaEndDTO.setDayCode(jsonObject.getString("dayCode"));
                            leaveStaEndDTO.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                            leaveStaEndDTOList.add(leaveStaEndDTO);
                            calenderLeavesTotal.setAdapter(new AdapterLeaveDateCalenderItem(getContext(),leaveStaEndDTOList));
                            progress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }catch (Exception e){

                            progress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (JSONException e) {

                    progress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Accept","application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization",utils.bear+utils.user_token);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    private void displayLeavesTypes(SelectDTO clickedDTo2) {

        int leaveType_id=clickedDTo2.getExpenseSelectDTOId();
        String leaveType_code=clickedDTo2.getExpenseSelectDTOCode();
        String leaveType_description=clickedDTo2.getExpenseSelectDTODescription();
        utils.creLeaveTypeId = String.valueOf(leaveType_id);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 0)
        {
            if(data != null)
            {
                try {

                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 200, 200, true);
                    picLoaderLeave.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                    encoded33 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    utils.creLeaveFile = encoded33;

                }
                catch (Exception e){

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            else{

            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 22){
            try {

                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage, 200, 200, false);
                picLoaderLeave.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                encoded33 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                utils.creLeaveFile = encoded33;

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you sending an array/arraylist to your adapter. when you edit the data, same data in that array/arraylist also edited. so use that.

Comment: but when i change the value of item at position using edit text and when i close the keyboard it again show me the last response text that get from server can you help me how can i change it

Comment: can you share your code here top help you?

Comment: i can share my code with you just wait a minute and thanks

Comment: i have updated the post with code 
Kindly give me solution Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to send whole list data into server? Just send updated one. I hope your list view items have unique id from server, just pass that id to server with updated data and update your list view locally on success of update api. If you don't have any unique id from server then ask your backend developer to add unique id with each item.

Comment: array that i get from from server is getting from another url
and where i want to post the updated array is another url 
thats why i want to send the whole arraylist to the server 
or i use edit text in list view but when i changed the list view value i dont know why but it also again shows me old value 
Not saving the updated value on that position how can i resolve it